# Populate PHP data in JQuery FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have a JQuery calendar plugin I'm using currently and as of right now I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to populate the calendar with information from a PHP file using AJAX.

```
var Script = function () {
```

//    calendar

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

window.onload = function myfunction() {
 var xmlhttp;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

} else {

xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../ajax/calendar.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    editable: false,
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
]
});
}();
```

This is the PHP File

```
<?

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1093'");

do {

$message = $row['message'];
$hour = $row['hour'];
$minute = $row['minute'];

$year = $row['year'];
$month = $row['month'];
$day = $row['day'];

$status = $row['status'];

if(eregi('pending', $status)) {

    echo '
    {<br>
        title: '.$message.',<br>
        start: new Date('.$year.', '.$month.', '.$day.', 12, 0),<br>
        end: new Date('.$year.', '.$month.', '.$day.', 14, 0),<br>
        allDay: false<br>

        },
    ';
    }

    }while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query));

} else header('location: error.php');

 ?>
```

How do I get the info from my database table to loop into my JQuery plugin?

Comment: Can you give an example of how the Javascript would need to look if you weren't loading it dynamically? You should be able to echo it the same way you've printed the data, it just depends how it needs to be formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier than you think, you can define your `events` property as an ajax call like so (right in your fullcalendar initialization):

```
...
events: {
    url: '../phpPath/pathToEventScript.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST"
},
...
```

just be sure that each event object (in your array of objects) has a `start` property.

PHP script:

```
$select = "SELECT title, start FROM events";
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$events = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($events);
```

Comment: You're right, it's much easier than I had thought. Json_endoce() worked.

Answer (score 1):

PHP have [a `json_encode()` method](https://www.php.net/json_encode) allowing you to convert PHP arrays to valid JSON objects.

Also make sure to output the correct content-type header.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($my_datas_from_DB);
```

Just output your content with this method so it can be consumed by JavaScript.

(Side note: JSON is not HTML, `<br>` wouldn't be valid here as you try to output JSON manually)

Answer (score -3):

Do something like this:

"your.js" could be something like this:

```
$.get( "../ajax/calendar.php", function( data ) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(eval("(" + data + ")"))
    alert( "Calendar initilazed ;)" );
});
```

and your php file havenot to include "< br >" tag as new line!

Comment: No :| Don't eval anything from a server.